# Not able to retrieve values from Berkeley DB in C

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I have two separate codes, one for inserting the data and one for retrieving the data in Berkeley DB using C. My problem is I am able to see that my data is stored and when I do a db->get immediately after db->put, I see the values. But when I try to do db->get via a separate code, I am having problems, the error I get is db->get: DB_NOTFOUND, when I don't use any delete function. Not sure where the error is

Inserting data code: (I pass a string from some other function into it)

```
int db_json(char *json) {

    typedef struct {                             
        char data1[500];    
    } pearson_record;

    pearson_record s;
    int i =0;
    DB *dbp;
    DBT key, data;
    int ret, t_ret;
    int recno;

    if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "db_create: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        exit (1);
    }

    if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, DATABASE, NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664)) != 0) {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "%s", DATABASE);
        goto err;
    }

    printf("data: %s\n",json);
    strncpy(s.data1, json, strlen(json)+1);

    recno = 1;

    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

    key.data = &recno;
    key.size = sizeof(recno);
    data.data = &s;
    data.size = sizeof(s);

    if ((ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key,&data,0)) == 0)
        printf("db: %d: key stored.\n", *(int *)key.data);
    else
    {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->put");
        goto err;
    }

    err:    
        if ((t_ret = dbp->close(dbp, 0)) != 0 && ret == 0)
            ret = t_ret; 

    return 0;
}
```

Retrieving data code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <json/json.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <db.h>

#define  DATABASE "mydata.db"

int main()
{
    typedef struct {                            
        char data1[500];
    } pearson_record;

    pearson_record s;
    int i =0;
    DB *dbp;
    DBT key, data;
    int ret, t_ret;
    int recno;               

    if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "db_create: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        exit (1);
    }   

    if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, DATABASE, NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664)) != 0) {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "%s", DATABASE);
        goto err;
    }

    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

    pearson_record *ppr;

    if ((ret = dbp->get(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0)) == 0) {   
        ppr = (pearson_record *) data.data;
        printf("db: %d: key retrieved: data was %s %d\n",
             *(int *)key.data, ppr->data1, data.size);
     }
     else {
         dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->get");         
    }
    goto err;

    err:    
        if ((t_ret = dbp->close(dbp, 0)) != 0 && ret == 0)
            ret = t_ret; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just tided up the formatting of the code blocks for you to make it easier to read. It's really unpleasant code, though: why are you `typedef`ing the same structure twice (within your functions, even) instead of in one header file that you include in both places; and there's no need to use `goto` in this kind of scenario.

Comment: Have you verified that the data is actually written to the database? using the db_dump tool?

Answer (score 0):

To use DB->get(), you need to know the exact key of the record you want to retrieve.  In your example, you'd have to set recno = 1 and then set up the key DBT to point to it prior to calling DB->get().

In the likely case that you don't know the key, what you want is DB->cursor() and DBcursor->get().  You can open a cursor for the database with DB->cursor(), and then loop calling DBcursor->get(curs, &key, &data, DB_NEXT).  This will return each record in the database, starting at the beginning.

There's a great example in the "Retrieving records with a cursor" section in the BDB Programmer's Reference here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/am_cursor.html#am_curget